# Condition using EOF in C

Tags: c

The code below is my answer to exercise 1-13 in K&R The C Programming Language, which asks for a histogram for the length of words in its input. My question is regarding EOF. How exactly can I break out of the while loop without ending the program entirely? I have used Ctrl-Z which I have heard is EOF on Windows, but this ends the program, instead of just breaking the while loop. How can I get to the for loop after the while loop without ending the file? This is a general question, not just with my code below but for all the code in K&R that uses: while ((c = getchar()) != EOF). Thanks in advance!
`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 20 /* Max length of a word */
#define IN 1 /* In a word */
#define OUT 0 /* Out of a word */

int main() {
  int c, i, j, len = 0;
  int lenWords[MAXLENGTH];
  bool state = OUT;

  for (i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i) {
    lenWords[i] = 0;
  }

  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {
      if (state == IN) {
        lenWords[len - 1] += 1; /* a length 5 word is in subscript 4 */
        len = 0;
      }
      state = OUT;
    }
    else {
      state = IN;
    }
    if (state == IN) {
      len += 1;
    }
    c = getchar();
  }

  /* Generating a histogram using _ and | */
  for (i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i) { /* Underscores write over one another; not so efficient */
    for (j = 0; j < lenWords[i]; ++j) {
      putchar('_');
    }
    putchar('\n');
    for (j = 0; j < lenWords[i]; ++j) {
      putchar('_');
    }
    putchar('|');
    printf("Length: %d, Frequency: %d", i + 1, lenWords[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` (Windows) and `Ctrl-D` (Linux) do not end a program, they end the console input (in Windows, only just after a `newline`). `Ctrl-C` might end a program, depending on configuration.

Comment: Using cygwin maybe? ^Z would suspend the program, which new users might misinterpret as being terminated. Cygwin terminal is designed to make unix users comfortable, so Windows terminal tips like "^Z= EOF" don't apply.

Comment: I tried your program (under MacOS) and, after changing `bool` to `int`, it compiled and seemed to work.  I typed control-D, and it stopped accepting input, and printed the histogram.  Control-D is the keyboard end-of-file character on Unix-like systems, including Linux and Mac OS X.  On Windows, of course, it's control-Z, and I think sometimes you may have to hit Return after typing control-Z, or something.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cygwin. I should have known that it wouldn't be the windows command.

Comment: @user1692570 I wonder whether you think accepting the answer might be a choice. According to your comment I thought it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question belongs on another network.

Answers here: [Equivalent to ^D (in bash) for cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/q/291224/447379)

> No. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on *nix generates a EOF, which various
>   shells interpret as running `exit`. The equivalent for EOF on Windows
>   is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, but cmd.exe does not interpret this
>   specially when typed at the prompt.

Comment: Feel free to accept. On the other hand. I recommend we flag your post as off-topic saying that it belongs to Superuser network.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to sends `EOF` to standard input and stops the read on *nix.

Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether you use *nix or windows.

On Windows, EOF is represented by `Ctrl+Z`, whereas on *nix EOF is represented by `Ctrl+D`